# Monitoring Windows 2008 R2 File Server Client Job Requests

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, monitoring, python

I would like to monitor the requests or incoming jobs (for example, if they transfer files or submit requests) to the file server by many workstations in the company. I would like to track their IP Adress and see from where each request or job was submitted. This is part of a monitor system that I am creating with python. Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by "submit requests"?

Comment: For example if a user downloads a file or uploads a file to the file server.

Answer (score 1):

minimally you'll need to turn on file auditing on the server, then you'll need to parse the security log for details.